# Trying to replace a file in middleware and not getting file content at server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying the replace an image in the middleware `InvokeAsync` method like this:

```
   public class SampleMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly Runner _runner;
    private readonly IStorageProvider _storageProvider;

    public SampleMiddleware(Runner runner, IStorageProvider storageProvider)
    {
        _runner = runner;
        _storageProvider = storageProvider;
    }
    private async Task<StreamContent> CreateStreamContent(IFormFile file, string path)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path));
        StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "attachment";
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.FileName;
        fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length; 
        return fileContent;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {            
        var request = context.Request;
        if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Post
            && request.ContentLength > 0
            && request.Path.HasValue
            && request.Path.Value.Contains("addAttachment", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
            if (form.Files.Count > 0)
            {                   
                IFormFile formFile = form.Files[0];
                MultipartFormDataContent requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                StreamContent streamContent = await CreateStreamContent(formFile, "PlaceHolder.png");
                requestContent.Add(streamContent, "attachment", formFile.FileName);
                foreach (var item in form.Keys)
                {
                    requestContent.Add(new StringContent(form[item]), item);
                }                                        
                Stream m = await requestContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                context.Request.Body = m;
                context.Request.ContentLength = m.Length;                                        
                // Continue the request pipeline
                await next(context);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }            
    }                
}
```

Here, My file is not passed into new content. I am getting an error like

```
Unable to find uploaded item information. null
```

Has anyone else tried to resolve this issue?

Comment: 400 error means the syntax of the client request is incorrect and the server cannot understand it. What's specific error message ? Could you show how to reproduce your problem ? If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Add a try/catch and see what the caught exception tells you.